# Can Snap install resume a failed download?

Tags: snap

Is there any resume support for snap?

```
android@android:~$ snap install shotcut --classic
Download snap "shotcut" (17) from channel "stable"                                22% 4.75MB/s 51.1serror: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "shotcut" (17) from channel "stable" (net/http: request canceled)
android@android:~$ snap install shotcut --classic
Download snap "shotcut" (17) from channel "stable"                                 0%  432kB/s 12.0merror: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "shotcut" (17) from channel "stable" (net/http: request canceled)
android@android:~$
```

Here i want snap to resume from my previous 22% download.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Snapd supports resuming downloads. If this is not working for you, please let the Snap developers know on the [Snapcraft forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io).

Comment: What does it look like when snap resumes an interrupted download? For me, it seems to start over from 0%. I just tried it now with `snap install android-studio`.